# Find functions such that under the Cartesian coordinate system $F(x, y) = f(x) g(y)$ but under the polar coordinate system $F(x, y) = h(r)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, contest-math, coordinate-systems

Find all non-constant function $F(x, y)\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that under the Cartesian coordinate system $F(x, y) = f(x)  g(y)$ but under the polar coordinate system $F(x, y) = h(r)$.

My thoughts: setting x=0 and y=0 we get $F(x,0)=F(0,x) = h(|x|)$. So $f(0)g(x)=f(x)g(0)$. WLOG, $g(0)=1$.
Now taking partial derivative w.r.t $\theta$ in $F(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=h(r)$, we get

$\frac{g'(x)}{xg(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{xf(x)}=\frac{g'(y)}{yg(y)}$ where $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$. So this equality is true for any $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

But if we suppose $\frac{g'(x)}{xg(x)}=\frac{g'(y)}{yg(y)}$ is true for any $x,y\in[-r,r]$, then we can set it equal to some constant $c_0$ and solve the differential equation. And we should get $F(x,y)=k\exp(c(x^2+y^2))$. But the challenge is to show this form of solution of unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you have already solved the problem, but didn't realise this.

Your argument shows that there exists an absolute (i.e. dependent only on $f,g,h$) constant $c_0$ such that $f'(x)/x f(x) = c_0$. (You don't really have to worry about the constraint $x,y \in [-r,r]$ - just argue that changing $r$ does not change $c_0$, and then take any $r$ large enough.)

It follows that $f(x) = k_1 e^{c x^2}$ with $c = c_0/2$, and $g(x) = k_2 e^{c y^2}$, and finally $F(x,y) = k e^{c x^2 + y^2} = k e^{r^2}$.

The above argument shows that: if $F$ satisfies the assumptions, then it is of the form $F(x,y) = k e^{c x^2 + y^2}$ - no other $F$ are under consideration. Now, of course, any function of the above form satisfies the assumptions - so, you have indeed classified them all.

Comment: Well, I only showed for any $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+y^2=r^2$, we have $f'(x)/xf(x)=f'(y)/yf(y)=c_0$. But this $c_0$ may be different for different $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Comment: No, I think it still works. You have shown that: If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, then $f'(x)/xf(x) = g'(y)/yg(y) = c_0(r)$. But, if you take any $r_1,r_2$ and sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ (say, $r_1,r_2 > \epsilon$) then you can substitute $y = \epsilon$ and get $c_0(r_1) = g'(\epsilon)/\epsilon g(\epsilon) = c_0(r_2)$ - hence, $c_0$ does not depend on $r$ after all. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'm not talking about $c_0$ being different for different $r$. In my comment $r$ is fixed. I showed if $x_1^2+y_1^2=r^2$, then $f'(x_1)/x_1f(x_1)=g'(y_1)/y_1f(y_1)=c_1$. Also if $x_2^2+y_2^2=r^2$, then $f'(x_2)/x_2f(x_2)=g'(y_2)/y_2f(y_2)=c_2$. But how do you show $c_1=c_2$?

Comment: Ah, right. But isn't it the case that: $f'(x_1)/x_1f(x_1) = g'(y_1)/y_1g(y_1) = f'(x_2)/x_2f(x_2)$, the first equality using the point $(x_1,y_1)$, and the second one using $(x_2,y_1)$?

Comment: But $x_1^2+y_1^2=r^2$ and $x_2^2+y_1^2=r^2$ is true iff $|x_1|=|x_2|$. So you didn't show it for arbitrary $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: But you don't need $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_1^2$. The reasoning you have shows that for $r = x^2 + y^2$ you get $f'(x)/xf(x) = g'(y)/yg(y)$. Now, if you take *any* $x,y$, you certainly can find suitable $r$. So you have the general rule saying that for any $x,y$: $f'(x)/xf(x) = g'(y)/yg(y)$